# how to have a monorepo with many sub-packages in python?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, monorepo

I have the following setup:

```
monorepo/
|_ sub_pkg1/
  |_ sub_pkg1/
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ func.py  # where there's a class A
  |_ setup.py  # sub_pkg1's setup
|_ sub_pkg2/
  |_ sub_pkg2/
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ func.py  # where there's a class B
  |_ setup.py  # sub_pkg2's setup
|_ setup.py  # monorepo's setup
```

I created a virtual environment inside `monorepo`'s folder: `python -m venv .venv` and activated it through `source .venv/bin/activate`, updated `pip` to the latest version, as well as the `setuptools`, and installed `ipython` for checking the setup.

The content of each setup:

`setup.py` from `sub_pkg1` sub-package:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="sub_pkg1",
        version="0.0.2",
        package_dir={"sub_pkg1": "sub_pkg1"},
        packages=["sub_pkg1"]
    )
```

`setup.py` from `sub_pkg2` sub-package:

```py
from setuptools import setup


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="sub_pkg2",
        version="0.0.2",
        packages_dir={"sub_pkg2": "sub_pkg2"},
        packages=["sub_pkg2"]
    )
```

finally, `setup.py` from `monorepo` package:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, find_namespace_packages

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="monorepo",
        version="0.0.2",
        package_dir={
            "sub_pkg1": "sub_pkg1/sub_pkg1", 
            "sub_pkg2": "sub_pkg2/sub_pkg2"
        },
        packages=["sub_pkg1", "sub_pkg2"],
    )
```

Then, I typed `python -m pip install -e .`.

**What happens**: there are no `sub_pkg1` and `sub_pkg2` installed. Actually, I got only `monorepo`. However, the weirdest thing is that when I enter `ipython`, there's no `monorepo` library to import from, rather `sub_pkg1` and `sub_pkg2` are available!

[image]

and

[image]

**What I want**: by doing `python -m pip install -e .` I can install both `sub_pkg1` and `sub_pkg2` on `pip` and be able to use them by importing `sub_pkg1` or `sub_pkg2`.

Comment: You're mixing up [distribution packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) with [import packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) in several places.

Comment: got it, @Brian61354270 . What should I do?

Comment: It's hard to say without more information. Do you need the `sub_pkg1` and `sub_pkg1` to be provided by their own distributions, or would it be ok if the `monorepo` distribution provided both?

Comment: Also, do note that `setup.py` is outdated. You should consider migrating to `setuptools` current `pyproject.toml` interface, or to a more modern build system like poetry, hatch, flit, etc.

Comment: as I mentioned, I want to only import either `sub_pkg1` or `sub_pkg2` without the need to call `monorepo`. `sub_pkg{1,2}` may be pypi independent distributions in the future, but by using `monorepo` I want to install all of them at once.

Comment: I was considering `pyproject.toml` as well, but most of the resources available are using `setuptools.setup`. I'm happy to use `.toml` if I can do it there, for sure!

Comment: The 2 libraries should be listed as dependencies, meaning they should be listed in `install_requires`, that's it. -- But honestly I am not sure the `monorepo` library is needed, is there really a need for `monorepo` to be its own project? Wouldn't it be better solved with something like a `requirements.txt` file or something to the same effect?

Comment: @sinoroc listed as dependencies only work if they're in the pypi repository, which is not the case (yet). Regarding the `monorepo` being a repo itself, it's pretty common having a repo for libraries that may be bundled together by installing it directly or installing each one individually as needed. Saves unnecessary installation when not needed or saves installing many things when they all are needed at once. Also, keeps them all up-to-date together as you need to merge a single monorepo.

Comment: The libraries have to be installed one way or another, otherwise the packaging metadata for those libraries will be absent or incorrect. What is wrong with a solution like `requirements.txt` in order to list the "concrete dependencies" on top of having the "abstract dependencies" listed in the `install_requires` of `monorepo`? I guess that would be the best solution from my point of view. [Abstract dependencies vs concrete dependencies](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/).